# Cubes and Subcubes

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, proof-verification

I just need my work to be checked. I've got the following problem:

Take a cube. It is colored red on the outside and white on the inside. Split it into 27 subcubes. Put them in a bag, shake the bag, and put one subcube on a table. You see that the five visible faces of the subcube are all white. What's the probability that this in the interior subcube (i.e. the one with no red sides)?

Here's my work:

Let $I$ be the event that the subcube is the interior cube. Let $S$ be the event that the subcube shows five white sides. We're trying to find $P(I|S)$.

By Bayes' Rule, $$P(I|S) = \frac{P(S|I)\cdot P(I)}{P(S)}$$

And clearly $P(S|I) = 1$, and $P(I) = \frac 1 {27}$. So: $$P(I|S) = \frac{1/27}{P(S)}$$

To compute $P(S)$, we enumerate the possibilities. There is $1$ interior subcube that shows 6 white sides. There are $6$ center subcubes that show $5$ white sides. There are $8$ corner subcubes that show $3$ white sides. There are $12$ edge subcubes that show $4$ white sides.

The corner and edge subcubes don't show enough white sides. The interior subcube shows $5$ white sides with probability $1$. We have a $\frac 1 {27}$ chance of selecting the interior subcube.

The center subcube shows $5$ white sides with probability $\frac 5 6$. The probability of selecting a center subcube is $\frac 6 {27}$. So the probability of selecting a center subcube and it showing 5 white sides is $\frac 6 {27} \cdot \frac 5 6 = \frac 5 {27}$.

Add the chance of selecting the interior subcube, and we have that $P(S) = \frac 6 {27}$.

So $$P(I|S) = \frac{1/27}{6/27} = \frac 1 6$$

As expected. But I've been told that this is not the right answer. Can anyone look over my proof to see if I'm mistaken somehow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The side that you can’t see is either the colored side of one of the face subcubes or any side of the interior subcube. That’s a total of $12$ possibilities, all of which are equally likely. In $6$ of the $12$ cases you’re looking at the interior cube, so the probability that you have the interior cube is $\frac12$.

The mistake in your calculation is that the face subcubes show $5$ white sides with probability $\frac16$, not $\frac56$.

Comment: Yes! That's exactly it! Now it comes out to $\frac 1 2$. I'd been told that was the correct answer. Thanks.

Comment: @Newb: You’re welcome.

Answer (score 1):

The error is in your computation of $P(S)$.  You should enumerate the possibilities as $27\times6$, which is the number of ways to pick a subcube *and* decide which side to set facing down.  If you count things this way, then the number ways to wind up with five white side visible is $6+6=12$, i.e., all $6$ ways of setting the inner cube down and $1$ way each for each of the $6$ center cubes.  This gives $P(S)={12\over27\times6}={2\over27}$, which should lead to the correct answer.

Or just listen to Brian Scott!